# Making custom Adapter Android but ArrayAdapter has no default constructor

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist, adapter

I'm 'extending' ArrayAdapter but when I try to use one of its constructors as super(); it complains saying "ArrayAdapter has no de-fault constructor".
I need it to store my ListView, Context and Data so it can be referenced anywhere... so, how do I solve this??
P.S. could it be my data-type for the List??

```
public class FeedAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>
{

    public FeedAdapter(Context context, int view, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list)
    {
        //TODO: WHY NOT WORKING??
        super(context, view, list);
    }

//Other code...
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  Always be specific about any errors what is different that what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public class FeedAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>
```

to

```
public class FeedAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<String>>
```

Also,

```
super(context, view, list);
```

to

```
super(context, view);
```

Comment: My data-model is a 2D ArrayList of Strings; will I still be able to use it if I do this??

Comment: Yes, you should be able to.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 why not pass `list` to the super constructor? as you suggest to change `super(context, view, list);`

to

`super(context, view);` any reason?